# What was the first movie that had only female characters?

Tags: first-appearance

What was the first movie that had only female characters? In a quiz competition that question was asked and I didn't know its answer. Although the question was for Bollywood but here my question is for both Hollywood and Bollywood.

Comment: Is the statement *"both Hollywood and Bollywood"* supposed to be generalizing to all movies from everywhere or indeed meant to limit it to Hollywood and Bollywood movies only?

Comment: I got the answer for Hollywood movies, but I also wants to know about Bollywood which is more important for me. @Walt

Comment: You need more parameters. Without parameters, I'm would go with "Woman Getting Into Bed" 1887, or something similar by Eadward Muybridge. You can watch some of his work on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6N2_82R90s

Answer (score 10):

[Mädchen in Uniform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A4dchen_in_Uniform) from 1931 about a girls boarding school must be a serious contender. From Wiki:

> The film was groundbreaking in a number of ways: firstly for its all-female cast; secondly for its sympathetic portrayal of lesbian "pedagogical eros" (see Gustav Wyneken) and homoeroticism [...] and thirdly for its co-operative and profit-sharing financial arrangements (although in practice these ultimately failed).

[The Women](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Women_%281939_film%29) is another 30s film (1939) with an all-female cast:

> Throughout The Women, not a single male is seen — although the males are much talked about, and the central theme is the women's relationships with them.