# What was the first US TV-series in which the main cast were mostly african american?

Tags: first-appearance

What was the first US television series in which the main cast were mostly african american?

Comment: We welcome this sort of question but we generally request that you put some effort into research yourself before asking. One sentence questions are generally considered low-quality, which is probably why your questions are being downvoted.

Comment: We have dozens of "first appearance" questions... I don't understand why this one is trivia and none of the others are not.

Comment: This question is under discussion on meta. However, I would like to point out here that there is no difference in content or quality with this question: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23691/what-was-the-first-movie-that-had-only-female-characters . If anything, my question is better because it does not include unnecessary information. Has the "on/off-topic"-policies changed since the linked question was asked?

Comment: That makes the reason this was put on hold even worse. I will delete the question since it is a duplicate, or whatever is the usual procedure.

Comment: The usual procedure is to mark as a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

That would be The Amos 'n' Andy Show from  1951–1953,  which centered around Harlem and starred the eponymous characters, two black men, and mostly black cast. Ironically, the tv show was based on a radio show where the two white creators voiced acted as the black characters.